# Powershell script to set dead lock priority

Tags: sql-server, powershell, transactions, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I am trying to Set DeadLock Priority for my Transaction in my Power shell script but the Deadlock Priority is not maintained across the transaction.

Its running for the first Transaction and dropping for the rest of transaction.

Import-Module SqlServer -Version 21.0.17199
 # Connect to your database. $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection $Connection.ConnectionString = "" $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand $Connection.Open() $Command.Connection = $Connection #$connection.Connect() #$Command.CommandText = "SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY 7;"; $server = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($connection) $database = $server.Databases[$databaseName] [String] $sql = "SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY 7;"; $result = $database.ExecuteWithResults($sql); $Connection.Close()

Comment: Add a minimal code example to your question.

Comment: Import-Module SqlServer -Version 21.0.17199
# Connect to your database.
$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = ""
$Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
$Connection.Open()
$Command.Connection = $Connection
#$connection.Connect()
#$Command.CommandText = "SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY 7;";
$server = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($connection)
$database = $server.Databases[$databaseName] 
[String] $sql = "SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY 7;";
$result = $database.ExecuteWithResults($sql);
$Connection.Close()